# Images from desktop to android filesystem

Tags: android, filesystems

I am trying to store multiple images from desktop to Android phone filesystem using Android Studio, rather than including the images in the resources/drawable folder. How do I go about doing this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You dont need Android Studio. If you connect your phone to the computer you can already copy files. Every user can. You do not need to be a programmer.

Comment: Could you be more specific? It appears as if you require some new way of doing something, but it is not clear neither what you want to achieve, nor how were you achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `Android Debug Bridge` (it comes with Android Studio) app for that purpose. Type in a terminal section:

```
adb push <path to files on desktop> <destination folder on Android device>
```